# CSS rule won't work when I have tag helpers in my anchor tag in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

everytime I add tag helper in anchor tag my css rule in the tag won't work but when I remove it, it's working. I need to use those tag helper for routing. I use asp.net core 6 mvc btw

It only works by applying inlnine css which is not a good practice. hope you can help me. I'm just a beginner btw.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Arima, welcome to SO! Please post a [reprex] so people can try to find the issue...